# SQLite: re-arrange physical position of rows inside file

Tags: sqlite

My problem is that my querys are too slow.

I have a fairly large sqlite database. The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
    timestamp TEXT,
    name TEXT,
    result float,
)
```

(I know that timestamps as TEXT is not optimal, but please ignore that for the purposes of this question. I'll have to fix that when I have the time)

"name" is a category. This calculation holds the results of a calculation that has to be done at each timestamp for all "name"s. So the inserts are done at equal-timestamps, but the querys will be done at equal-names (i.e. I want given a name, get its time series), like:

```
SELECT timestamp,result WHERE name='some_name';
```

Now, the way I'm doing things now is to have no indexes, calculate all results, then create an index on name `CREATE INDEX index_name ON results (name)`. The reasoning is that I don't need the index when I'm inserting, but having the index will make querys on the index really fast.

But it's not. The database is fairly large. It has about half a million timestamps, and for each timestamp I have about 1000 names.

I suspect, although I'm not sure, that the reason why it's slow is that every though I've indexed the names, they're still scattered all around the physical disk. Something like:

```
timestamp1,name1,result
timestamp1,name2,result
timestamp1,name3,result
...
timestamp1,name999,result
timestamp1,name1000,result
timestamp2,name1,result
timestamp2,name2,result
etc...
```

I'm sure this is slower to query with NAME='some_name' than if the rows were physically ordered as:

```
timestamp1,name1,result
timestamp2,name1,result
timestamp3,name1,result
...
timestamp499997,name1000,result
timestamp499998,name1000,result
timestamp499999,name1000,result
timestamp500000,namee1000,result
etc...
```

So, how do I tell SQLite that the order in which I'd like the rows in disk isn't the one they were written in?

UPDATE: I'm further convinced that the slowness in doing a select with such an index comes exclusively from non-contiguous disk access. Doing `SELECT * FROM results WHERE name=<something_that_doesnt_exist>` immediately returns zero results. This suggests that it's not finding the names that's slow, it's actually reading them from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Normal sqlite tables have, as a primary key, a 64-bit integer (Known as [rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) and a few other aliases). That determines the order that rows are stored in a B*-tree (Which puts all actual data in leaf node pages). You can change this with a [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table, but that requires an explicit primary key which is used to place rows in a B-tree. So if every row's `(name, timestamp)` columns make a unique value, that's a possibility that will leave all rows with the same name on a smaller set of pages instead of scattered all over.

You'd want the composite PK to be in that order if you're searching for a particular name most of the time, so something like:

```
CREATE TABLE results (
    timestamp TEXT
  , name TEXT
  , result REAL
  , PRIMARY KEY (name, timestamp)
) WITHOUT ROWID
```

(And of course not bothering with a second index on name.) The tradeoff is that inserts are likely to be slower as the chances of needing to split a page in the B-tree go up.

Some pragmas worth looking into to tune things:

- [cache_size](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size)
- [mmap_size](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_mmap_size)
- [optimize](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_optimize) (After creating your index; also consider building sqlite with [SQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_stat4).)

Since you don't have an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, consider [VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) after deleting a lot of rows if you ever do that.

Comment: Ok thanks for this. I'm worried that adding timestamp to the indexes will make insert slower. However truth be told, it shouldn't be very bad, since the calculation of the results is currently orders of magnitude slower than the inserts anyway. I'll let you know if your solution increases speed of select when I have the chance to test (currently takes me about a third of a day to generate one of these dataasets).

Comment: Actually... I'll just create a new table with the schema you suggested, and copy the results over from my table.

Comment: Well, this is gonna take forever. If I do the naive thing, which is `INSERT INTO your_schema SELECT * FROM my_schema`, it's gonna be writing things to disk in a way that same names are physically close, but every time it writes a row, it'll have to move over all the names next to it. So it'll take forever. I would say that you're on to something, but it's not a complete solution. Any further ideas?

Comment: Yeah, anything involving copying millions of rows is going to take a while

Comment: No, that's not the issue. The issue is that they're scattered across the disk. The "solution" I eventually came up with is read sequentially using ROWID to paginate the entire dataset, and in each "page" the disentangle names in memory into timeseries columns, and store into a format that's more appropriate to read columns, like HDF. Lets compare: a "name" has of order half a million rows. On sqlite if they're not stored contiguous, takes about half a min to read one "name" even with an index. From HDF takes less than a second